# Get value from element in the clicked class

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple instances of the same class with different values inside and I want to write a jquery function that can get the value of the class clicked.Right now my function returns blank.

Here is the html that I have

```
<div class="named" > <h5 value = "1"> value 1 </h5></div>
<div class="named" > <h5 value = "2"> value 2 </h5></div>
```

and here is my jquery function

```
$(".named").click(function(){
console.log($(this).find("h5").val());
});
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".named").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("h5").attr("value"));
});
```

You should really be using the [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and [jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
<div class="named"> <h5 data-value="1"> value 1 <h5></div>
<div class="named"> <h5 data-value="2"> value 2 <h5></div>

$(".named").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("h5").data("value"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`value` is not a valid attribute of an h5-tag. You should probably change that to `data-value`(html5) and then either use the attr-method or the jQuery data api:

```
<div class="named" > <h5 value = "1"> value 1 <h5></div>
<div class="named" > <h5 value = "2"> value 2 <h5></div>

// With attr
$(".named").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("h5").attr("data-value");
});

// with the data api
$(".named").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("h5").data("value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".named").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("h5").attr("value"));
});
```

headers don't take values, so they consider them attributes